# Cannot access deployed spring-boot RESTful API in Minikube

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Good day!

I bumped into this post:
https://cleverbuilder.com/articles/spring-boot-kubernetes/

And It seems I am able to run my spring-boot RESTful application as it is showing in the Minikube Dashboard. The problem is when I try to execute `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl get svc` I am not seeing my application. The kubernetes namespace that my application using is `test`. I'm really puzzled now on how can I access my application. Please shed some light. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `kubectl get pods -n test`, `kubectl get svc -n test`. let me know, what you get ?

Comment: Hi @sulabhchaturvedi the results are my applications pod and service. so my namespace is incorrect when I deployed it in minikube? Am i getting this right?

Comment: Okay, let me write a clear answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run, `kubectl get pods -n test`, `kubectl get svc -n test` and this should show you the desired output.

By default, `Kubernetes` starts with the following three namespaces: `Default`: Catch-all namespace for all objects not belonging to either of the `kube-public` or `kube-system` namespaces. The `default` namespace is used to hold the default set of pods, services, and deployments used by the cluster. Since, your pod is in a `custom` namespace `test` (you created). You'll need to specify the namespace where your deployment is been created or pod is been deployed.

So, `kubectl get pods` is actually `kubectl get pods -n default` meaning show pods in default namespace. hence, doing `kubectl get pods -n test` will show you all your pods in `test` namespace.

[See Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Comment: So now I am sure that my application has been deployed. How do I access it? I want to see my working URL by running "minikube service <myApp>". Would the -n parameter still be possible for that?

Comment: You need to expose your pod via a service. I suggest please ead on Kubernetes Services  - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: @Oneb - can you please accept this as an answer, if I answered the question you had posted ?

Comment: I already have a service. What I noticed is the External IP is blank.

Comment: what type of service do you have ? If you have svc type `clusterip`, you can access your service only from within the cluster, if you have  svc type `nodeport`, you can access it frm the same host as that of minikube (just a different port)., if you have type `loadbalancer`, you can simply use loabalancer details

Comment: actually i'm running fabric8 using NodePort as type but when it is deployed in the kubernetes instance, it says clusterIP. weird. @_@

Comment: I suggest ask another question, explain it and share your service configuration